# How does tikz-3dplot parse keys?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to draw in spherical polar using `tikz-3dplot` and I don't understand how some of the `\td...` commands parse their args. What I do is define a pic, which takes 2 arguments (using `/.style` args) and define a coordinate based on them. Then I want to pass a macro as one of the arguments and this is where funny things happen.

If I wrap the macro around {} (which is I guess the preferred way of separating it from the following arguments) then all is fine but if I write \{} (which in normal TeX should also separate it from the following text and not raise an error) then the tikz-3dplot commands fail, which commands such as \node work.
If this is not clear, I hope the MWE helps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\def\aj{-4} % gives an error Undefined control sequence if I use \aj{}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\aj}{1} % same as above
%\def\aj#1{-40} % works
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,
  pics/state/.style args={#1 #2}{code={
      \node at (#1,#2) {}; % this works
      % this line also gives an error if I use \aj{}
      % \tdplotsetcoord{psi}{1}{#1}{#2}
    }},
  ]
  \pic[red] {state=\aj{} 2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When TeX encounters a control sequence, all following spaces are skipped.  That is to say, that `\aj 90` is seen as `\aj90`, but the parser expects an explicit space between the two arguments.  Your options are thus, `\aj{} 90` or `{\aj} 90` or `{\aj} {90}` (or perhaps even more).  You could also define the style to take the following signature `#1,#2` and then use `state={\aj,90}` which is not affected by skipped spaces.

Comment: you can also directly use `pics/state/.style args={#1 #2}{code={\tdplotsetcoord{psi}{1}{#1}{#2}\draw[->] (0,0,0) to (psi);`

Comment: @percusse Sure, I initially had that, I think I added the intermediate step while I was trying to figure out what the error was about and forgot to remove it.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, I figured this was the problem when the macro is not the final argument (hence followed by }) so I tried escaping the space by writing \aj\ left but that didn't work, which I found surprising. In any case. There is a difference when I'm using tikz alone compared to tikz-3dplot, which is the main thing that bugs me - any ideas?

Comment: By writing `\ ` you do not *escape* the space.  The construct `\ ` is a control sequence by itself, implemented as a primitive to *typeset* a space.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for reminding me, now it makes sense.

Comment: The comment on `\def\aj{-40} % always gives an error` is probably wrong.  This *has* to work.

Comment: @HenriMenke It gives an error with tikz-3dplot (If I use \aj{} ) when it works with tikz and this is my main question - why? I just tried \def\aj{-40} and using {\aj} inside the argument list (instead of \aj or \aj{}) and it does work but still... tikz allows me to write \aj{} even if I define \aj to not take arguments which makes sense). I will update my OP with a reduced MWE to show exactly this.